# Is there a better way to find and replace html site files?

Tags: html

I've a large 1000 page site I'm trying to edit. I tried a find and replace with Dreamweaver but apparently the template is broken and split up. So when I do a find and replace it updates the template and messes all up.

I tried expression web but it crashed after 200 pages.

Is there another way to find and replace code on a html site that works well?

Comment: Are you using a content management system (CMS) such as Wordpress or another? I use Atom to write code and the search and replace tool shows files in a list. It may or may not be too convenient depending upon the environment. I use it on static websites without an issue. However, for coded sites, you will have to have internal knowledge as to how the site is configured and works. Cheers!!